# Php, get properties of object, except unset-ted

Tags: php, reflection

```
class Example
{
    private $fa, $fb;

    public function u()
    {
        unset($this->fb);
    }
}

$example = new Example();
$example->u();
foreach((new \ReflectionObject($example))->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE) as $v)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($v);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

it will print even `fb` although its been unsetted.

Comment: Class property is unset in __current instance__ of class, `Reflection` gathers info about class description, not about current state of class instance. So, I suppose, you __cannot__ achieve what you want.

Comment: Indeed. As you can see in this [example](https://eval.in/836423) the property on the object's instance has been unset.

Comment: yes, but thats why I used ReflectionObject, not ReflectionClass